# component-wise conditional / piecewise-defined operations in eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to implement using eigen something like (pseudocode):

```
A = BooleanExpr(X) ? ExprTrue : ExprFalse;
```

where all variables are Eigen::Array's. That is for each component of X, if BooleanExpr on that component is true, the corresponding component of A is computed as  ExprTrue, otherwise it's ExprFalse.

I implement it at the moment like:

```
COND = BooleanExpr(X).cast<double>();
A = COND * ExprTrue + (1-COND) * ExprFalse;
```

But this computes both Expr* on each component, which doesn't feel right when Expr's are expensive.

In fact I would like to generalize this to a piecewise-defined function of X, so I can compute something like (pseudocode):

```
A = PieceExpr[ IntExpr(X) ] ( B );
```

that is the result of an integer expression on component of X determines expression used to compute the corresponding component of A.

May be I'm just going the wrong way about it and there is a way to achieve the same result in eigen already, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need .select() as documented at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a7c7f8804e216885f49b70f61c7ae3bbb (I think that this works on arrays and matrices, contrary to what the documentation suggests).

For the more general situation, I don't know a nice way to achieve this other than nested selects.

Comment: also, as far as I understand, contrary to what argument names suggest the thenMatrix and elseMatrix can be expressions and only the one or the other will be computed per component (because the argument types are DenseBase and not MatrixBase).